# Cannot create file in Network folder in c#

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am calling the Reporting Services from my website and writing the output file to a network share. My setting in IIS is Windows authentication and Impersonation = True.

I am using this below code to render and create the file in Network share.

```
results = rsExe.Render(sRptFormat, deviceInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out Warnings, out streamID

using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(sFileName))
{
    stream.Write(results, 0, results.Length);
}
```

But getting an error saying "access denied" to create this file. I have my username in the folder share as full control.

How can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going through the Windows share and you have permissions on the share, you will still also need NTFS permissions on the actual folder, in addition to the permissions on the share.  Perhaps this is where you're running into a problem.  The NTFS permissions are configured by right clicking on the folder and going to Properties > Security.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I did set all the folder permission correct. The IIS uses the authenticated user till calling the Reporting Server and when it try to write to the folder the authentication is changed to ANONYMOUS.